# How to remove the controller name from url in codeigniter, and still be able to redirect on another controller?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, http-redirect, codeigniter-routing

I'm building an website using Codeigniter and I've changed the way the URL looks from `http://localhost/site_controller/home` to `http://localhost/home`.

I've changed that by using .htaccess -> RewriteBase
changing the `$config['index_page']` to `$config['index_page'] = '';`
and in routes I've change like that:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site";

$route['(:any)'] = "site/$1";
```

And it works fine only for the **site** controller, **BUT my problem is that I have another controller** named admin and when I try to login and make a redirect using redirect('admin/index') I get a 404 error.

How can I redirect from site controller to admin controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to route from `(:any) => site` you have to specify a higher priority route for the admin controller that overrides that route for those pages.

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site";

$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/$1";
$route['(:any)'] = "site/$1";
```